# Django dynamic filtering with optiona parameters over M2M fields

Tags: django, listview, filtering, m2m

i'm trying to do a ListView accepting optional parameters to be used as filters for the queryset.

Now, i've my model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name,self.surname)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)


class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author,blank=True, null=True)
    conf = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

and i mapped the url in this way

url(r'^publications/(?P.*)/', PublicationList.as_view(), name='publication-list'),

the idea is to append the optional parameters after `publications`, something like 
`year=2012` or `year=2012&tags=food` or `year=2012&tags=food,car&authors=bobby`
so something that give me freedom on doing the filtering.
Btw, is this the correct/standard way to pass multiple parameters via url?

now, i've this ListView Class

```
class PublicationList(ListView):
template_name = 'publications.html'
context_object_name='pubs'

def get_queryset(self):
    ...
```

with `self.kwargs['optional']` i can get the full string of the parameters. but: do i've to do all the cases on the data to do the filtering?
so do the split on & then do a for on the resulting list (`args`) and check for each value (`arg`) if it's year (`arg=='year'`) then do `filter(year=arg)`?

is there anything that does this for me or something better?

in addition, since i've a m2m relationship with tags and authors, how can i do the same filtering over tags for example? basically i've to check if the tags values match any of the `tag.name` in the M2M relationship.

ciao

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend either using [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter), or taking a look at how it does what it does. Essentially it takes form input, and builds a queryset using the parameters passed in from the form.

The problem you're trying to solve isn't easy in the general case.

Comment: do you know a running example of this? i'm trying to understand what it exactly does.

Comment: It does the same as the django admin more or less. It configures the URL like so `http://www.domain.com/view/?relatedmodel__field=blah&field=yes&otherrelatedmodel__field=something` and the query params are passed directly to a `filter` as kwargs

Comment: Josh, don't you know if this app uses _exactly_ the same code as django admin app does?

Comment: Exactly the same? No. But the principles are similar, and the code is similar (though more complete). You might want to check out one of the more recent forks though.